# Nhibernate Joining another table

Tags: nhibernate, c#-4.0, fluent-nhibernate

I need to perform a join on the customer. Where address is primary and populate PrimaryAddress1 and PrimaryCity field. Customer mapping already has hasmany relationship with address class but I do not want to fetch all addresses (performance issues).

Please help..

classes:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        Addressess = new List<Address>();
    }
   public virtual int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual int? BranchID { get; set; }
    public virtual int? CustTypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Prefix { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string PrimaryAddress1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string PrimaryCity { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}


public class Address
{
    public Address()
    {
    }
    public virtual int LocationID { get; set; }
    public virtual int? CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual string LocationName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address3 { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Primary { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
public TblCustomerMap()
{
    Table("tblCustomers");
    LazyLoad();
    Id(x => x.CustomerID).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("CustomerID");
    Map(x => x.ProfileID).Column("ProfileID");
    Map(x => x.BranchID).Column("BranchID");
    Map(x => x.DateEntered).Column("DateEntered");
    Map(x => x.DateTerminated).Column("DateTerminated");
    Map(x => x.CustTypeID).Column("CustTypeID");
    Map(x => x.CompanyName).Column("CompanyName").Not.Nullable().Length(50);
    Map(x => x.Prefix).Column("Prefix").Not.Nullable().Length(50);
    Map(x => x.FirstName).Column("FirstName").Not.Nullable().Length(50);
    Map(x => x.MiddleName).Column("MiddleName").Not.Nullable().Length(50);
    Map(x => x.LastName).Column("LastName").Not.Nullable().Length(50);
    HasMany(x => x.Address).KeyColumn("CustomerID");
    Map(x => x.PrimaryAddress1).Column("PrimaryAddress1") // from table tbladdress where address is primary and get data from address1 column
    Map(x => x.PrimaryCity).Column("PrimaryCity") // from table tbladdress where address is primary and get data from city column
}
```

Query:

```
 var query = session
            .QueryOver<Customer>(() => customer)
            .JoinQueryOver(() => customer.Addresses, () => address)
            .Where(() => address.Primary)
            .List();

        foreach (var customer1 in query)
        {
            customer1.PrimaryAddress1 = customer1.Addresses[0].Address1;
            customer1.PrimaryCity = customer1.Addresses[0].City;
            customer1.PrimaryState = customer1.Addresses[0].StateOrProvince;

        }
```

New query:

```
  var query = session.Query<Customer>()
            .SelectMany(c => c.Addresses,
                        (c, a) => new {c, a})
            .Where(cust => cust.a.Primary)
            .Select(item => new CustomerView()
                              {
                                 CustomerID = item.c.CustomerID,
                                 CompanyName=  item.c.CompanyName,
                                 FirstName=  item.c.FirstName,
                                  LastName=item.c.LastName,
                                  Address1=item.a.Address1,
                                  Address2=item.a.Address2,
                                 Address3= item.a.Address3,
                                 City= item.a.City,
                                 StateOrProvince= item.a.StateOrProvince
                              });
        return query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways how to achieve this.

1) The more intuitive and readable is extending DB and adjusting *NHibernate* mapping. We will need new *view* `viewPrimaryAddress` to be created.

```
SELECT ***columns*** FROM [tbladdress] WHERE Primary = true
```

And Customer mapping will look like this:

```
Join("[viewPrimaryAddress]", 
{
  m.Fetch.Join();
  m.KeyColumn("CustomerID");
  m.Map(t => t.PrimaryAddress1).Column("PrimaryAddress1");
  m.Map(t => t.PrimaryCity).Column("PrimaryCity");
});
```

And that's it. One SQL Statement will be issued, so no need to load the Address collection

*2) Oveview of the second approach*

The second approach will create that view by a new class mapping, is a bit complicated, but can be done only on the application side (C# & NHiberante).

New class `PrimaryAddress` will be created and contain the ilter on a class level definition (xml mapping example:

```
<class name="PrimaryAddress" ... where="Primary = true" >
```

Then we can extend `Customer` with new *many-to-one* relation to `PrimaryAddress`. So getting properties for column "PrimaryAddress1" and "PrimaryCity" would be done via SQL select filtered in the WHERE Clause.

#### EXTENDED:

Next steps should guide you how to create new mapping, targeting the primary address as the one-to-one property
1) C# PrimaryAddress:

```
public class PrimaryAddress
{
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
}
```

2) Mapping:

```
public TblPrimaryAddressMap()
{
    Table("tbladdress");
    LazyLoad();
    Where("Primary = 1");
    // Id as AddressId
    References(x => x.Customer).Column("CustomerID");
    Map(x => x.Address).Column("PrimaryAddress1")
    Map(x => x.PrimaryCity).Column("PrimaryCity")
}
```

3) New property for `Customer`

```
public class Customer
{  
   ..
   public virtual PrimaryAddress PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
```

4) New mapping for `Customer`
public TblCustomerMap()
{
  ...
  HasOne(x => x.PrimaryAddress)

At this moment, when you get `Customer` from session. You can access

```
customer.PrimaryAddress.Address
customer.PrimaryAddress.City
```

*I am working with XML mapping mostly. But from these lines the concept should be clear... Playing with some `fetch="join"` you can load `Customer` and its `PrimaryAddress` in one SQL select*

*And if you need even customer property `Customer.PrimaryAddress1`, just wrap the PrimaryAddress.Address in the getter.*

What you'll gain more, is possiblity to filter and order by over this new property `PrimaryAddress`

**NOTE**: this approach is fragile for Caching. The reason is, that whil you will change the real `Address` entity, there is no built mechanism to evict `PrimaryAddress`. And also, you should force the business layser to allow only Customer with one Address set to primary = true

Comment: thanks heaps for your reply. i will be working with legacy database with no right access.. can you please elaborate more more about the second approach? thanks again

Comment: yeah, I touhgt so;) I know these legacy DB. Anyhow, I extended the second approach...I believe that you will see how It was menat, because my domain is XML mapping. The concept is working, I used it many times in similar scenarios

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar address structure and struggled with this. One major concern is ensuring that a Customer record is returned if the Customer has no primary address (shouldn't happen but...).

Take a look at [join mapping](http://ayende.com/blog/3961/nhibernate-mapping-join) if you want to include the address fields in the Customer entity.

My approach is to use a data transfer object (DTO or view), in this case CompanyDto:

```
    internal static QueryOver<Company> GetCompanyDtoQuery()
    {
        Address addr = null;
        CompanyDto dto = null;

        var query = QueryOver.Of<Company>()
            .Left.JoinAlias(c => c.Addresses, () => addr)
            .SelectList(list =>
                        {
                            list.Select(c => c.CompanyId).WithAlias(() => dto.CompanyId)
                            list.Select(a -> addr.AddressId).WithAlias(() => dto.AddressId
                            return list;
                        })
            .Where(a => addr.AddressId == null || addr.IsPrimaryAddress)
            .TransformUsing(new AliasToDtoDeepTransformer<CompanyDto>("PrimaryAddress"));
        return query;
    }
```

[EDIT]

It's easier to do this using Query, for example:

```
            var target = (from c in session.Query<Company>()
                          from a in c.Addresses
                          where a.IsPrimaryAddress
                          select new
                              {
                                  c.CompanyId,
                                  a.Address1
                              })
                .Take(10).ToList();
            Assert.IsTrue(target.Any());
```

The problem with the query you posted is that you are forcing a lazy load by accessing the collection by index. You can use eager loading to fetch all the addresses in one select:

```
             var target = session.QueryOver<Company>()
                                 .Fetch(c => c.Addresses).Eager
                                 .Take(10).List();
             Assert.IsTrue(target.Any());
```

However, as I said in my original reply you should look at join or another approach instead of including fields from another table in your domain model.

Comment: Can I be bold and ask what is `AliasToDtoDeepTransformer` ?

Comment: @Rippo it's an IResultTransformer implementation that can set properties on nested objects. I would probably use a mapper or some other means to do this now.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. will query be faster than another  primaryaddress object? I think it will be but what are your thoughts

Comment: please check updated query. i have to loop through all the addresses to populate the primaryaddress1, primarycity and state field. That loop is making the operation slow. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @JamieIde I have updated the query with nhibernate query instead of fluent nhibernate. It is working but I wish is could write fluent nhibernate query to be consistent with the project..

Comment: @sunny The new query is written using LINQ extension methods which is newer than QueryOver. I like the syntax much better, especially for mapping properties to other objects.